# Is there any way to have more than one word in the label in LyX?

Tags: spacing, lyx, lists

In LyX, when I use "labeling" under "Lists", the first word I type is turned into a label followed by a large space. Is there any way to have more than one word as the label. LyX isn't allowing me to use more than one word as the label.

Comment: To use more than one word, instead of a normal space press ctrl+space (that is the shortcut on Linux and I imagine also Windows. I don't know about Mac).

Comment: Labels are converted into macros using \csname \endscname (generally with a few other letters added in).  So the question is really, why can't I have spaces in a macro names?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I can add two words now. But I still can't figure out how to increase the indentation made by a label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is heavily dependent on the LyX interface separating the first word from the rest, and making it the label. As such, it seems best to fool LyX in think you're still typing the first word by using a non-breaking space - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - for setting subsequent words:

[image]

Note that the `lyxlist` environment defined under the Labeling List uses a default label width equivalent to the width of `00.00.0000`. So, using multiple words longer than this might influence the layout.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to increase the default horizontal space after each label?

Comment: @user1992705: See the updated answer using a Local Layout.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the only solution. Lyx should accept `[multiple word item label]` as a [description item label](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Description).